# How to conver base64 to image php

Tags: base64

I have base64 data in http://pastebin.com/TZUeECM3

how can to convert its base64 to jpg or png and save in folder.
here is my code

```
$filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
$decoded=base64_decode($base64_string);
file_put_contents("uploads/".$filename_path,$decoded);
```

Answer (score 6):

base64 code contain the **"data:image/png;base64"** just remove it and then try to decode even it doesn't work then replace blank space with **"+"** and decode

```
$filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
$base64_string = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64_string);
$base64_string = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_string);
$decoded = base64_decode($base64_string);
file_put_contents("uploads/".$filename_path,$decoded);
```